# Повторить цикл for

Tags: java, массивы, матрицы, max

Хочу чтоб цикл `for` повторился, но проверил 2 столбец матрицы, за счет `value++;`, и при проверке столбца выдало "упорядочен" или нет, столбец по убыванию. И как найти максимум в упорядоченном столбце (не верхний элемент (что логично), а чтоб код искал максимум при условии, что столбец упорядочен по убыванию (это 1 столбец).

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int value = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int[][] mass = {{3, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 1}, {0, 3, 1}};
    /*mass[0][0] = 3;
    mass[0][1] = 2;
    mass[0][2] = 1;
    mass[1][0] = 1;
    mass[1][1] = 2;
    mass[1][2] = 3;
    **/
    for (int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mass[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(mass[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    job:
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (mass[i][value] <= mass[i + 1][value]) {//проверка убывания
            System.out.println("Столбец1 не упорядочен");
            value++;
            continue job;
        } else {
            sum++;//чтоб не повторялось по 3 раза , что он упорядочен
            if (sum == 3) {
                System.out.println("Столбец упорядочен");
                value++;
                continue job;
            }
            value++;
            continue job;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Можете перефразировать ваш вопрос нормальным языком? Ничего не понятно что вы хотите

Answer (score 0):

Объясняете задачу вы , мягко говоря,  непонятно. Посему вот вам методы длл получения по номеру колонки 2-мерного массива максимального и минимального значения, а также проверки на порядок по возрастанию и убыванию. 2 написаны циклами ,а 2 стримами.

```
public static boolean isDescending(int[][] mass, int columnNumb) {
    int tmp = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int[] mas : mass) {
        if (tmp > mas[columnNumb]) return false;
        else tmp = mas[columnNumb];
    }
    return true;
}
public static boolean isAscending(int[][] mass, int columnNumb) {
    int tmp = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int[] mas : mass) {
        if (tmp < mas[columnNumb]) return false;
        else tmp = mas[columnNumb];
    }
    return true;
}
public static int maxValueByColumn(int[][] mass, int columnNumb) {
    return valueByColumn(mass, columnNumb).max().getAsInt();
}
public static int minValueByColumn(int[][] mass, int columnNumb) {
    return valueByColumn(mass, columnNumb).min().getAsInt();
}
private static IntStream valueByColumn(int[][] mass, int columnNumb) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, mass.length - 1).map(i -> mass[i][columnNumb]);
}
```